# Ruby gem show "Invalid argument" error for almost every command

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nativescript

I am working through NativeScript's set-up on **OS X El Capitan** and I am stuck at the point where I am supposed to install `xcodeproj` and `cocoapods`. Almost everything that I try to do with `gem` shows the same error:

```
$ sudo gem install xcodeproj
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EINVAL)
    Invalid argument
```

The following commands show the same error, wether I run it with `sudo` or not:

```
$ gem update --system
$ gem update
$ gem install whatever
$ gem install cocoapods
```

I have the following versions:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]

$ gem --version
2.6.7
```

I've tried some of the help that I've found online, including reinstalling `gem` and `ruby`, restarting but nothing has helped.

I guess that I have a configuration problem with Ruby.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I am getting the same issue as well, and one of my rails apps is now broken. This is after a `brew upgrade` this morning. Something in the brew upgrade seems to have broken ruby, although I haven't figured out how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using RVM or `rbenv`? Is that all you get or is there a stack trace?

Comment: @tadman: I am not sure. Probably neither. How can I verify that? I used brew to install Ruby and then I followed the instructions here to install gem: https://rubygems.org/pages/download

Comment: `gem env` usually explains in more detail. `gem` should come with Ruby, there's rarely a reason to install it independently. For what it's worth, I'm using 10.11 and `rbenv` Ruby 2.1.3p112 and gem 2.6.7 and `xcodeproj` installs fine. Can't reproduce this particular issue, but maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just had a similar issue after updating everything via Homebrew.

I solved the issue by uninstalling Ruby and installing it via rbenv, then reinstalling cocoa pods.

Steps:

1. Uninstall ruby

   `brew uninstall ruby`
2. Install rbenv and ruby-build

   `brew install rbenv ruby-build`
3. You need to add Ruby to your path.

   A. If Terminal is your shell.

   Add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to `~/.bash_profile`

   B. Or if you use another shell

   You can find the instruction by entering the command `rbenv init NAME_OF_YOUR_SHELL`.
4. Install Ruby

   `rbenv install 2.3.1`
5. Set the Ruby version

   `rbenv global 2.3.1`

   `rbenv local 2.3.1`
6. Reinstall Cocoapods

   `gem install cocoapods`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It fixed the issue for me. I edited it to add steps for newbies like me.

Comment: Instead of step number 3, run `rbenv init Your_Shell's_Name` to get instructions on how to properly do that in your shell of choice. In my case for example, I ran `rbenv init fish`